# How to get the last email sent with the Mandrill API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, mandrill

I would like to know if there's way to get the last email send with the `Mandrill` API?
I looked over the documentation but I didn't find any method to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use this call to get recently sent message meta data:

https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/messages.JSON.html#method=search

And then this one to get the full message content for a given message:

https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/messages.JSON.html#method=content

Comment: Yes, I used this call and put the limit to `1` and I got the last message sent! Thank you!